# Running Web API 2 with IIS Express

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I cannot seem to run my Wep API 2 project through the terminal using IIS Express. I'm using a virtual machine on my Macbook, so not sure if that is causing the issue.

I get the following error while attempting to run `iisexpress`:

> zsh: command not found: iisexpress

**What am I trying to solve?**

> I would like to run my C# Web API 2 project using IIS Express through the terminal. This is necessary so that I can run my integration tests against the API while it is running.

**Machine Setup:**

- MacBook Pro running Windows 10 with Parallels.

**Questions that I have:**

1. Why can I not run the following command: `iisexpress`?
2. How do I run my Visual Studio project with IIS Express?

Repo:
https://github.com/ChaseHardin/GroceryHub

I've also attempted at running my Web API by starting the API in the background `Ctrl + F5` and then pointed my API test project to that port, but get the following error:

`The operation could not be completed.`

I've looked through Google to find an answer but can't seem to get it working. The main point of reference was: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line

Project Directory:
[image]

Comment: `zsh` indicates you are trying to run a Shell command called `iisexpress` on Mac. That's completely wrong, as IIS Express command line is only available on Windows.

Comment: @LexLi yes, I’ve also run this on my virtual windows machine and get the same error minus the zsh part.

Comment: `iisexpress` is not a global command. As the document indicates, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line#running-a-site-using-iis-express-from-the-command-line you have to first navigate to the installation folder.

Comment: @LexLi agreed, I navigated down into my iiexpress installation: `/c/Program Files/IIS Express` and get this error: `bash: iisexpress: command not found` when running `iisexpress`

Comment: it is weird that you chose to use Bash on Windows but without even knowing how Bash works. Use ˋ./iisexpress.exe` then and it might work. All Microsoft documentation assumes you use Command Prompt which simply supports the documented command.

Comment: @LexLi thank you for that comment, I can now run iis, but not sure how to make it run my web api. Could you help me get that running?

Comment: @LexLi I uploaded a picture of my directory.

Comment: without asking others you can see from the same document what switches are offered. Just like man page for Linux/UNIX commands you can learn how to run IIS Express with sites.

Comment: Will do... only asked cause I spent a couple nights working on this with minimal progress.

Comment: From where did you get the source code? It comes with a readme file and it must have original developers.

Comment: From where did you get the source code? It comes with a readme file and it must have original developers who can help you further.

Comment: @LexLi  I wrote all the source code.

Comment: When you run such projects in VS, it automatically generated an IIS Express config file, which later you can use to run your site from command line. https://blog.lextudio.com/jexus-manager-secrets-behind-visual-studio-iis-express-integration-834f88c8e8b?source=---------25---------------- Thé simpler way is to run such sites on full IIS.